# Understanding ISO-TP, Flow Control and Blocksize

Tags: communication, can, bus, flow-control

I am currently trying to understand can communication using the ISO 15765-2 (ISO-TP) and Unified Diagnostic Services (UDS) Protocols using can.

At this point I have a question about the Flow Control Frame.

Imagine I have this frame given:

[image]

So far I understood the 0x3 says that this frame is a Flow Control Frame and the 0x0 says that my communication can continue sending consecutive frames.
My question is now about the Blocksize (0x0F if I am correct).

The 0x0F means that it expects to have 15 more frames to come, right?
So if my communication does not send 15 frames but just one, it would lead to an error, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. It depends on your library use. If the library you use handles that it might be cause problems or not. Also the ISO-15765 standard does not specifies any requirement when a sender fails to send a flow control and keep going on. In short 0x0F tells the sender side "SEND ME 15 CONSECUTİVE FRAME" and Sender sends the 15 consecutive frames and expects flow control again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).